# Does System.arraycopy use clone() method?

Tags: java, deep-copy, shallow-copy, arrays

I have an array of objects with an overridden `clone()` method. When I use `arraycopy()` func, will it copy every element through the `clone()` method or it makes a shallow copy? 
Thanks

Comment: It will just copy the references to the objects, not the objects themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both, `System.arraycopy(...)` as well as `Arrays.copyOf(...)` just create a (shallow) copy of the original array; they don't copy or clone the contained objects themselves:

```
// given: three Person objects, fred, tom and susan
Person[] people = new Person[] { fred, tom, susan };
Person[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(people, people.length);
// true: people[i] == copy[i] for i = 0..2
```

If you really want to copy the objects themselves, you have to do this by hand. A simple for-loop should do, if the objects are `Cloneable`:

```
Person[] copy = new Person[people.length];
for(int i = 0; i < people.length; ++i) copy[i] = people[i].clone();
```

Another, maybe more elegant solution is provided since Java 8:

```
Person[] copy = Arrays.stream(people).map(Person::clone).toArray(Person[]::new);
```

Answer (score 4):

System.arraycopy produces a shallow copy of the array part specified.

Comment: So the `for` loop is the only way for a deep copy?

Comment: by providing a copy constructor for the element type of the array, you could eg use `java.util.Arrays.stream(objs).map(T::new).toArray(T[]::new)` to create an array of deep copies